# How to include first initials when using authoryear referencing format (harvard) with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style, drop-cap

My university has its own kind of Harvard referencing that requires first initial as well as surname, im struggling to find out how to insert this using biblatex.
my current code for referencing is:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[firstinits=true,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2
```

From bibliography file:

```
@article{Chen2017,
   author = {Chen, Hui and Manso, Gustavo},
   title = {Macroeconomic Risk and Debt Overhang*},
   journal = {The Review of Corporate Finance Studies},
   volume = {6},
   number = {1},
   pages = {1-38},
   ISSN = {2046-9128
2046-9136},
   DOI = {10.1093/rcfs/cfw007},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

I'm using `\parenthcite{<key>}` to cite my sources

according to previous answers on here, including 'firstinits=true' should render the initial into my citation command, but thats not happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The option `firstinits`, which was renamed to `giveninits` a few years ago now, only changes the name formatting from showing full given names to given name initials. Where `biblatex` did not show any given names to start with the option has no effect.

By default `biblatex`'s `authoryear`-based citation styles will only print given names or given name initials in citations to resolve ambiguities due to non-unique family names (if you cite Jane Smith and Anne Smith, `biblatex` would use J. Smith and A. Smith, so your readers can immediately tell that the authors are different). This feature is controlled by the `uniquename` option.

If you want given name initials in all citations and full given names to resolve ambiguities (Jane Smith and John Smith), you can redefine the `labelname` field format. (The original definition can be found in [`biblatex.def`, ll. 955-981 in v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L955-L981))

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}<2
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \else
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, 1998)]

Comment: Brilliant, this works perfectly thank you!

Comment: @boovey If the post helped answer your question, please consider accepting the answer to mark the problem as resolved, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.