# footcite equals texcite with special format (parenthesis around year and given name initials)

Tags: biblatex, footcite

I need to use a special `footcite` and `textcite` format for my master thesis. They should both look like

```
Cite with footnote and textcite.\footnote{Vgl. \textcite{A01}, S. 23.}
Cite with footcite.\footcite[Vgl.][S. 23]{A01}
```

[image]

I tried different solutions for the initials in `footcite`, but they would corrupt the output of `textcite`. Here is the version without the initials.

[image]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8,
style=ext-authoryear,
giveninits=true,
dashed=false,
doi=false,
date=year,
isbn=false,
uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,        
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% footnotestyle format
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Parathenthesis around year in footcite
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

% indentation
\usepackage[hang,bottom,stable]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{5mm}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 

% given name initials for footcite and textcite
% ???

\begin{document}
Cite with footnote and textcite.\footnote{Vgl. \textcite{A01}, S. 23.}
Cite with footcite.\footcite[Vgl.][S. 23]{A01}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error: a comma after `isbn=false` is missing. With this correction the output will corresponds to the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `labelname` name format. The original definition can be found in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 955-981 in v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L955-L981). (Cf. also [How to include first initials when using authoryear referencing format (harvard) with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578904/35864.))

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  dashed=false,
  date=year,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifnum\value{uniquename}<2
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \else
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
Cite with foonote and textcite.\footnote{\Cite[Vgl.][23]{nussbaum},
  and much more text.}
Cite with footcite.\footcite[Vgl.][23]{nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Nussbaum, M. (1978), S. 23//Vgl. Nussbaum, M. (1978), S. 23]

---

I wouldn't use `\textcite` here because you don't want its placement of pre- and postnote. But you can easily repurpose `\cite` for that job.

In the example I would definitely prefer

```
 \footcite[Vgl.][23]{nussbaum}
```

over

```
 \footnote{\Cite[Vgl.][23]{nussbaum}.}
```

but if you include additional text (as in the MWE), it may make sense to use the latter form.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Thats it! And yes, I only use `\cite` in `\footnote` when i want to cite something in a longer footnote. My MWE was maybe not precise enough.